# Proof for local minima

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Proof that in case of convex function locally optimal point is also globally optimal

[image]

[image]

From : CS229, Convex Optimization Overview by Zico Holter, October 2008.
http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-cvxopt.pdf

My question is why :
$$\theta f(y) +(1- \theta) f(x)<f(x)$$

For $\theta = 0$ : 
$$f(x)=f(x)$$

Is it a mistake in notes or I am overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y$ is a global minimum while $x$ is not in the contradiction setting,

$$R < \left\| x-y\right\|_2$$

$$\theta = \frac{R}{2\left\| x-y\right\|_2}<1$$

Also, note that $\theta >0$.

Remark: I think your concern is when $\theta = 0$ rather than $\theta = 1$. $\theta$ here is a particular value in $(0 , 1)$.